# Words for someone who gives up his moral standards?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am not sure if the word "fallen" matches the moral context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Compromised**" is the first alternative that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot this word in my mind pool!